# Is it possible to use python string format method with matplotlibs latex capabilities?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With matplotlib, it is possible to use latex to label axes and plots. i.e.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                         'C': [11, 12, 13, 14,15]})
data['A/B'] = data['A']/data['B']
plt.plot(data['C'], data['A/B'])
new_name1 = 'new_name'
new_name2 = 'new_name'
plt.title(r'$\frac{A}{B}$')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like to combine latex with python's string `.format` method. (While not necessary in this abstracted example, it is in my own work).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                         'C': [11, 12, 13, 14,15]})
data['A/B'] = data['A']/data['B']
plt.plot(data['C'], data['A/B'])
new_name1 = 'new_name1'
new_name2 = 'new_name2'
plt.title(r'$\frac{\{\}}{\{\}}$'.format(new_name1, new_name2))
plt.show()
```

gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/b3053674/Documents/LargeStudy/large_study/plot_locally.py", line 912, in <module>
    plt.title(r'$\frac{\{\}}{\{\}}$'.format(new_name1, new_name2))
KeyError: '\\{\\}'
```

and

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                         'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                         'C': [11, 12, 13, 14,15]})
data['A/B'] = data['A']/data['B']
plt.plot(data['C'], data['A/B'])
new_name1 = 'new_name'
new_name2 = 'new_name'
plt.title(r'$\frac{{}}{{}}$'.format(new_name1, new_name2))
plt.show()
```

gives me:

```
ValueError: 
\frac{}{}
     ^
Expected \frac{num}{den} (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
```

Is it possible to use string formatting with latex in this way? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You need three braces:

```
plt.title(r'$\\frac{{{}}}{{{}}}$'.format(new_name1, new_name2))
```

The inner pair `{}` will be formatted using the given variables, and the outer `{{` and `}}` are [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for single `{` and `}`.

Comment: Aaah of course, switching to latex means we need to use latex escape characters. Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @CiaranWelsh Not really, `{{` is a python string format escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `printf`-like formatting:

```
data = "\frac{%s}{%s}" % ("A", "B")
```